# Installing GCC after flashing SD-Card / Buildroot Distro

Tags: gcc, stm32, buildroot, gnu-toolchain

I am brand-new to Buildroot and didn’t use embedded systems or distros a lot.

I successfully flashed my STM32 and have **buildroot as distro** on it but after flashing it I figured out that I needed to install gcc package.
I didn’t find the gcc package after `make menuconfig -->target packages`. In fact not all packages listed in the buildroot/package/ Directory are listed in the `menuconfig` target packages interface.

I am really a noob and it would be great if you orient me step by step in order to get this done.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you need **native compiler on the target** in Buildroot. But Buildroot do not provide `native toolchain` after **Buildroot-2012.11**.

For more details refer : https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#faq-no-compiler-on-target

If you really need `native toolchain` try a *real distribution* like

- openembedded
- yocto
- Fedora

I think this helped you !